# List of spam IPs in SQL format

Tags: php, sql, spam-prevention

I have following table in my MySQL databse :

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virt100706_wie`.`banned_ips` (
  `idbanned_ips` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `ip` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `reason` TEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idbanned_ips`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I wanna to add to it the list of IPs, which are sending spams, belong to hackers, botnets, etc. etc. and permanently block access for it to my website.

I have found a good list [here](http://spam-ip.com/spam-blacklist.php), but it is published in CSV format and I need that in SQL format (`INSERT` statements).

My question is : **Is there any list of spam IPs publihsed in SQL format ?** or **Is there any tool to convert CSV to SQL `INSERT` format ?**

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you - the programmer - being the tool for it. however, using phpmyadmin you can import csv files as well

Comment: @hek2mgl I think entering 892875 row to database manually isn't pleasant... PhpMyAdmin can import CSV files ?

Comment: Of course I meant that you should write a script. (I said programmer) !!! :)  yes, phpmyadmin can do that for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to do this sort of thing sometimes. It's right on the borderline of being a task worth writing a script for. Usually I don't write a script - I'll use an emacs keyboard macro, but if your editor doesn't support keyboard macros, here's another way:

- Open the CSV in a spreadsheet program
- Write a formula column that substitutes in the values in the correct places
  (this assumes IP addresses are in column A)

  `="INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ('" & A1 & "',NOW());"`
- fill down the formula

Then copy and paste the result into the editor and save as a `.sql` file.

Comment: In LibreOffice I see "Err:522"

Comment: IP adresss is in B column

Comment: OK, great - I was thinking perhaps the syntax for concatenating might be slightly different, this was based on Excel...

Comment: No, that was logic error. Just fixed

Answer (score 3):

You can create SQL INSERT statements yourself from downloaded csv file.
Pipe your file through proper 'awk' command and write the output to a file - see below.
Than use the file as your SQL INSERT feed.

This command will create SQL you need:

```
$ tail -n+2 spam-ip.com_10-28-2013.csv | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ", " } ; {print "INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES (\"" $2 "\",now());"}' > spam-ip.com_10-28-2013.sql
```

Example pipe output:

```
$ tail spam-ip.com_10-28-2013.sql
INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ("61.191.191.154",now());
INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ("95.79.195.2",now());
INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ("194.8.75.54",now());
INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ("218.247.161.37",now());
INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ("94.75.193.168",now());
INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ("94.142.128.220",now());
INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ("212.157.248.198",now());
INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ("99.228.96.58",now());
INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ("92.112.40.145",now());
INSERT INTO virt100706_wie.banned_ips (ip,date) VALUES ("118.35.46.144",now());
$
```

Than something like:

```
$ mysql -u XXX -p virt100706_wie < spam-ip.com_10-28-2013.sql
```